# Xcode 5, How do I call a method when the user leaves the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Hello I do not have very much programming experience and I'm trying to call a method when the user leaves the app. I know that I am going to use the app delegate methods `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but how do I make that call a method that is in my `ViewController` class?

Thanks so much for any help!

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
//Images and buttons
}

-(void)stop;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a notification here. Create a listener for this notification in the viewDidLoad of the viewController and assign the function to it.
eg:

in yourView controller add the following in the viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationEnabled) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Ok I added that to my viewController's viewDidLoad, now what else do I do?

Comment: The selector in the above code is the name of the function that you want to call once the notification is received. The function will automatically be called when your app goes to Background.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

1. observe **UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification** inside your ViewController, or
2. invoke your ViewController method inside appDelegates `applicationdidEnterBackground:` method. App delegate should have a pointer that points to the **rootViewController**, ie: your ViewController

goodluck!

*edit:*

```
...
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

UIViewController *uvc= [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

ViewController *myvc = (ViewController*) uvc;
[myvc stop];

}
.
```

Comment: Ok so what code goes in the method applicationdidEnterBackground? I tried [myMethod]; and it gave me an error

Comment: u need to invoke your method with an instance of your viewcontroller class, ie: [myViewController myMethod]; if this is what u mean. I will add some code to my answer

Comment: Its not working, it says:  No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares selector'stop'

Comment: (stop is the method I'm trying to call)

Comment: heres my ViewController.h             -(void)stop;

Comment: can someone please answer, I'm pressed for time

Comment: you can cast it to your own class, if you are certain that rootViewController is indeed MyViewController class. see edits

Comment: ok I copied and pasted that into my code and it gave me two errors. for line two: "Unknown type name 'MyViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?" and for line 3:No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares selector'stop'

Comment: dude, cut and paste your codebase here. What .h files you have? maybe its name simply as ViewController (instead of MyViewController)

Comment: the only .h file that come preinstalled when you open a new project

Comment: Replacing the my with UI narrows it down to one error, No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares selector'stop'

Comment: yup, your view controller class is ViewController, I updated code, see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you close or leave your App, AppDelegate methods automatically called, you not need to call them in some specific ViewController.

For doing something when your App is in background you can implement your logic in **AppDelegate's** `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.

Or if your App is not running(means closed) **AppDelegate** Method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called.

Comment: in his question, @AwesomeTN has specifically asked "how do I make that call a method that is in my ViewController class"...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the purpose of calling the method inside UIViewController. Eventhough you can create an instance of your viewcontroller inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` and call the corresponding method in viewcontroller using that object

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating an instance of that View and then calling specific method of that view

otherwise if your view is opened then you can find it by follwing code & then call specific method by using that obj as follow in your `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
NSArray *AllViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

for (UIViewController *aViewController in AllViewControllers) {
    //NSLog(@" >> Nav Stack  %@", [aViewController class]);
    if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {
        [(YourViewController *)aViewController yourMethodToCall];
        break;
    }
}
```